# Visual studio code Installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, visual-studio-code

I used instruction from VSC web page  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

```
~$ sudo dpkg -i code_1.8.1-1482158209_amd64.deb
```

But have this error:

> (Reading database ... 65442 files and directories currently
>   installed.) Preparing to unpack code_1.8.1-1482158209_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking code (1.8.1-1482158209) over (1.8.1-1482158209) ... dpkg:
>   dependency problems prevent configuration of code:  code depends on
>   libnotify4; however:   Package libnotify4 is not installed.  code
>   depends on libnss3; however:   Package libnss3 is not installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package code (--install):  dependency problems
>   - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ... Errors were encountered while processing:  code

Thank you.

Answer (score 31):

Did you run the `sudo apt-get install -f` command after you got those errors? That command should install missing dependencies.

Comment: After installation and run /usr/bin$ code it was another problem,  it showing missing libraries 

libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libXss.so.1
libgconf-2.so.4

I install all of them.  


No error!!!!   Only one problem when I  run /usr/bin$ code -  nothing happened. no error but no application running.  


Any ideas?  
Thank you

Comment: It's working now. Thank you for your help.   Konstantin.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue a couple of weeks ago. This issue raised on VSCode's Github was suspended stating that there wasn't any sufficient information on the issue. I managed to install it anyway by the following way:

```
sudo apt install libgconf-2-4
```

The above command installs the missing library.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Then, do the command to install VSCode.

```
sudo dpkg -i code_1.25.1-1531323788_amd64.deb
```

Navigate to the location of the downloaded file while doing the above commands.

Answer (score 3):

One other command which helped me and might be useful for people -

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. use the app store
2. use `sudo apt install <application>`
3. download `.deb` installation file and use `sudo apt install ./file.deb`

I solved my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54171711/installing-vscode-deb-package-using-terminal-in-ubuntu-18-04)