# Installing vscode .deb package using terminal in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, dependencies, installation, ubuntu-18.04

I want to install Visual Code in ubuntu-18.04 with .deb package, i used: `dpkg -i <file name.deb>` i also tried: `apt-get install -f`

but it says it needs libconf-2-4, and libconf-2-4 needs more things...

Is there any way to install all of the dependencies together?

Comment: You should put the error output on your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apt` for installing a package ***file***, e.g.,

```
apt install ./filename.deb
```

The "./" helps it see that is just a package file, and after that it will continue by evaluating dependencies.